# Did Trish Walker get injected?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

In *Jessica Jones* season 2, Malus was helping Trish Walker to get superpowers but while he was going to inject her during the final step Jessica Jones comes.  But do we really know if he was able to inject her or not? As her powers got hinted in last episode. So did she get the injection or did she get powers from the partial procedure?

Answer (score 2):

## No

There was no "final injection"...but we don't actually know if the injection was intended to be part of the procedure.

On the contrary, it *appeared* that the procedure was going wrong, Patsy was seizing, and the injection was to control it or fix it. He doesn't reach for the hypodermic until something does go wrong.

The doctor says "I can fix it" and/or "I can help"...when trying to give her injection

Thus, **if** Patsy has powers (and it's strongly hinted that she does [or will]) then it was from the procedure...partial or otherwise.